# Think something's wrong with my ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What I want to do is return the echo value of "addTemplate.php" when I send it a form value via a http POST request. However, when I send the request, absolutely nothing happens.

What should I do?

Here's my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sendTemplate").on("submit", function(event) {
        var template = $("#template").val();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({method: "POST", url: "addTemplate.php", data: template, success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="adminscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Admin/Developer page</h1>
        <form id="sendTemplate">
            <p>Enter a new template for the server: (Enter #word to enter a placeholder for words)</p><input type="text" name="template" id="template">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
        <div id='success'></div>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <form action="turing.html">
            <button type="submit">Home</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my php

```
$template = $_POST["template"]; 
if(strlen($template) <= 100 && strpos($template, "#word")) {
    file_put_contents("templates.txt", "\r\n" . $template, FILE_APPEND);
    header("Location: http://community.dur.ac.uk/h.j.g.baum/admin.html");
    echo "True";
}
else {
    echo "False";
}
```

What's wrong with my code (most likely in the JavaScript) and how can I improve it?

Thanks

Comment: the data sent in your ajax needs to be an object or a serialized string. I suggest using `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: There r so many options now OP

Answer (score 1):

Replace ajax data:

```
data: template,
```

With:

```
data: "template="+template,
```

**Issue:**

You are using **$_POST['template']** for getting values and didn't define in ajax data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a closing curly on the Ajax success function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sendTemplate").on("submit", function(event) {
        var template = $("#template").val();
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({method: "POST", url: "addTemplate.php", data: template, success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sendTemplate").on("submit", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "addTemplate.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your js to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sendTemplate").on("submit", function(event) {
    var template = $("#sendTemplate").serialize();

    $.ajax({method: "POST", url: "test.php", data: template, success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }});
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And

```
<form id="sendTemplate">
```

to

```
<form id="sendTemplate" method="POST">
```

This is the right way to get the form data and pass it to your php script